# Dynamically receive newly created windows environment variables with python

Tags: python, environment-variables

Quick question with not much code to follow. I have a program that will be passing 4 windows environment variables via winrm to me. I will know 3 of these 4 values and can search for them by using the os module and writing them like below.

```
target = os.getenv('OS')
tool = os.getenv('TMP')
record = os.getenv('TEMP')
```

These 3 variables won't be looking for those exact 3 environment variables but the point is that the environment variable will be static. The fourth environment variable is unknown though and while there will be a set amount of environment variables, this number may not be small and could have a lot of different options. I don't think a list of all possible environment variable names to pick from would be best here. Is there a way to get whatever variable is passed along to me and store it in my config here? Of course config may not use getenv()

```
config = os.getenv('x')
```

The config environment variable will point to a yaml file with configuration details for the tool. 
This is with python. I will be placing all of these environment variables into a json object after I can get that fourth variable.

Comment: _"Is there a way to get whatever variable is passed along to me and store it in my config here?"_ Can you explain a bit more what you mean by that? Passed along to you how?

Comment: You don't explain how you are planning to recognize the fourth value.  `os.environ` will give you all environment variables as a dict. But if you are expecting your Python program to find out about *new* environment variables that were set after its process started, I think you are out of luck. Processes inherit a copy of the environment that was present when they were started. They don't get notified of updates.

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
target = os.getenv('OS')
```

you are not searching, as you indicate, but you are just retrieving.

If you want to search for an environment variable that points to a YAML file you should do something like:

```
import os

from config import my_config  # or something to get your configuration instance

for envvar in os.environ:
    if os.environ[envvar].endswith('.yaml'):
        if some_other_test_to_make_sure_this_is_the_env_var_you_want:
        config.add_yaml(os.environ[envvar])
        break
```